# No puedo visualizar datos en postman

Tags: postman

tengo la siguiente consulta que en el controlador que me devuelve todos los usuarios de mi base de datos:

```
public function index()
    {
        $usuarios= User::all();
        return $usuarios;
    }
```

pero a la hora querer visualizar en postman la consulta no me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

sin embargo en el explorador si se puede visualizar la consulta en formato json.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo hacer para poder visualizar la consulta en postman?

Comment: Agregaste `Accept: application/json` en los headers de postman?

Comment: no, como hago eso? perdon soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Veo que en postman usas una petición con el método HTTP POST, Intenta cambiar a GET. Ya que en el navegador la petición se realiza mediante GET y no POST.

Comment: gracias eso funciono

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes poner esa consulta en GET y no POST

Comment: gracias eso funciono